# Search functionality like the one here on stackoverflow's Users page

Tags: java, database, search

I need to built a search functionality like the one here on [StackOverflow's Users page](https://stackoverflow.com/users), where users are always sorted by their scores but may be filtered by the typing in a part of the name.

My application has been built in Java using a NoSQL database. Could you suggest what tools may be appropriate for this implementation.

Would it be good if I retrieve all usernames matching the query and then sort them by the scores at the application level, at each request of user ? Then there would be a lot of unneccessary retrievals, & may be performance issues as well.

Are there some better ways perhaps by maintaining an already sorted list (sorted by names as well as by reputation)?

Also, great, if someone can tell about how SO actually does this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jquery](http://jquery.com/) + ajax (for search) + [lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html) (to index content and search)

Comment: do I need to maintain a separate server for lucene ? Where does it store the data ?

Comment: nope! you can store it on your file system, or RAM or wherever you like. read about it and am sure you'll like it. that's what I use when I am dealing with large data sets

Comment: will try that out thanks for pointing! Could suggest some simple easy links to start with ?

Comment: the [wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/FrontPage?action=show&redirect=FrontPageEN) is a good starting point ...

Answer (score 1):

Try [datatables](http://datatables.net). But you will need to work on UI part.

Comment: that means you are suggesting to load the entire data from the database at once like if there are around 1000 results to be shown, then I should retrieve all of them at once ? This may be good for a small result set but not worth for 1000s of them.

Comment: @Raj: Ya it is not good for such scenarios. May be you can restrict the number of records displayed, select few records and display them. (Even in SO user page they show only few top users)

Comment: yes but the results are sorted page wise even there & for that you need to read all data from DB anyway..

Comment: @Raj: Completely agree. I used Ajax to load records as required. Let me know if you get any other better solution.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with aishwarya, is it good idea to use [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html)
It provides a lot's of features such as: wildcards, fielded searching, term/field/document weights, find-similar, spell-checking, multi-lingual search and more